# Python 2 - Only importing some modules in sub-directories

Tags: python-2.7, import, module, subdirectory

This is Python2.7.  I have seen some instructions to create a file which reads the directory structure, and pulls every .py file in as an include, but it hinges usually around having **file**, which I cannot use (or have not gotten to work).

I have a series of modules which have a several directories.  Let us start with the structure:

```
\\Scripts:
    script.py  # from ProgramName import *
\ProgramName
    __init__.py # empty
    FileA.py     
    FileB.py
    FileC.py
\ProgramName\SupportFilesA
    __init__.py # empty
    FileX.py    # contains class fileX()
    FileY.py    # contains class fileY()
    FileZ.py    # contains class fileZ()
```

And yet, for some reason, I can access classes fileX and fileY, but not fileZ.  Ok, the classes are significantly more complex than that, so I copy FileX and create FileXX.py, with class fileXX().  This also doesn't get picked up.

There are no errors on the compile of any of the files.
In the script, the import * doesn't fail.
I simply cannot make x = fileZ() or x = fileXX().

Comment: I think `import *` should not pick up the `FileX` class either: it should be namespaced as `SupportFilesA.FileX.FileX`. Since that appears to be not the case, you're either doing something fancy in your script, your `__init__.py` files is actually not empty, or you're picking up `FileX` from somewhere else (check `FileX.__file__` and such).

Comment: Also, clean up all `*.pyc` files; that may cause problems, for example if you originally had `FileX.py` in your `Scripts` directory and the `FileX.pyc` still lingers on in that directory.

Comment: Even if I do: 
from ProgramName.SupportFilesA.FileZ import *
I get:
ImportError: No module named FileZ

I have deleted all .pyc files in both ProgramName and ProgramName\SupportFilesA, and there are no pyc files in the \\Scripts directory.

Comment: that sounds like the root directory is actually not in your `PYTHONPATH`, but some other directory is, and that's where you're picking up the `FileX` class from. Print out `sys.path` before you run your import; also, again: print `FileX.__file__` or similar to find out which `FileX` you're actually importing.

Comment: I hate to admit it, but that was correct.  In the sys.path, was a directory that must have been the SysAdmin auto-saving heavily important data.  I went directory-by-directory through sys.path until I found another replica of ProgramName.  Deleted it.  imported ProgramName, a bunch of .pyc's appeared, and the entire thing worked.  I feel a bit foolish, but grateful for the solution I wouldn't have found myself.